# Stop JS selecting same image twice from defined variables

Tags: javascript, html, math, background-image, var

My JS is applying a random background image from a defined set of variables (`var images =`) to `div` elements with classes `image01`, `image02`, `image03`, and `image04`. How do I stop my JS selecting the same image twice between classes?

HTML

```
<section id="grid" class="desktop-image">        
    <div class="image-grid">
        <div id="image" class="image01"></div>
        <div id="image" class="image02"></div>
        <div id="image" class="image03"></div>
        <div id="image" class="image04"></div>
    </div> 
</section>
```

JS

```
var images = ['PK1.jpg','PK2.jpg','PK3.jpg','PK4.jpg','PK5.jpg','PK6.jpg','PK7.jpg','PK8.jpg','PK9.jpg','PK10.jpg','PK11.jpg','PK12.jpg','PK13.jpg','PK14.jpg',
'PK15.jpg','PK16.jpg','PK17.jpg','PK18.jpg','PK19.jpg','PK20.jpg','PK21.jpg','PK22.jpg','PK23.jpg','PK24.jpg','PK25.jpg','PK26.jpg','PK27.jpg',];

$(".image01").css({'background-image': 'url(assets/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
$(".image02").css({'background-image': 'url(assets/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
$(".image03").css({'background-image': 'url(assets/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
$(".image04").css({'background-image': 'url(assets/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of images that have been already chosen randomly.

```
var images = ['PK1.jpg','PK2.jpg','PK3.jpg','PK4.jpg','PK5.jpg','PK6.jpg','PK7.jpg','PK8.jpg','PK9.jpg','PK10.jpg','PK11.jpg','PK12.jpg','PK13.jpg','PK14.jpg',
'PK15.jpg','PK16.jpg','PK17.jpg','PK18.jpg','PK19.jpg','PK20.jpg','PK21.jpg','PK22.jpg','PK23.jpg','PK24.jpg','PK25.jpg','PK26.jpg','PK27.jpg',];

let usedImgs = [];
let imgNames = [".image01", ".image02", ".image03", ".image04"];

imgNames.forEach((img) => {
  let randImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  while (usedImgs.includes(randImg)) {
    randImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  }
  $(img).css({'background-image': 'url(assets/' + images[randImg] + ')'});
  usedImgs.append(randImg);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I am still getting repetition of images

Comment: @Serene Edited my answer. Try again now.

Comment: Thanks again, however the addition of ```usedImgs.append(randImg);``` has caused all images to disappear completely

Comment: @Serene OK try now pls

Comment: Just seeing one image now, all the others are not visible at all. P.s. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: any other ideas regarding this? I'm at a bit of a dead end with it